# how to call mysqldumper externally (not cron)

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

i'm developing a php web application and wondered how to backup the database.

i found [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.de/), but i dont really have an idea **how to force mysqldumper to make a backup within my web application.**

well, and i dont like the idea of having a user, who does not have a clue of databases, who has access to mysqldumper and must click himself through mysqldumper-application to make a manual backup.

does anyone have experience with this?

i think calling the "filemanagement.php" with appropriate params would do it, but i cannot think of how will i handle the page-reload behavior...

otherwise, does anyone know a proper alternative to mysqldumper, which is easily callable within an php application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on this website: [Perform a MySQL dump with PHP](https://www.net24.co.nz/kb/article/AA-00241/21/Shared-Hosting/PHP/How-to-perform-a-MySQL-dump-with-PHP.html)

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(600);

system("mysqldump -h localhost -u YOURUSERNAME -p YOURPASSWORD YOURDATABSENAME > /usr/local/www/vhosts/YOURDOMAIN.CO.NZ/private/BACKUPFILENAME.sql");

?>
```

Comment: Interesting, but what if i dont have shell access by a hosting provider?

Comment: I think it's impossible with this solution if you don't have a shell access... I don't know how to do without a shell access sorry